# React checking of a URL exists

Tags: javascript

I am building an app at work that with a table the brings up a details page which displays part information, as well as a download link ( ...url/variouspart#.pdf) to a PDF with additional information. The problem lies in that not every part has additional information since information gets added and removed form the directory constantly, so currently if the used hits "download" on a part with no additional info, they get an error.

So my question is, can someone show me a way to check if the URL is valid when I load the component?  Then if the URL leads to a PDF, I can conditionally display a "download available" button or display nothing.

Comment: Changing tag to Javascript, since this is not a React-specific question

Answer (score 1):

The given code returns, depending on the given URL, whether there is a PDF file under this location - if there is, it displays information. If the given URL location is not a PDF file, but e.g. HTML, it returns a different message. If nothing exists under the given URL, it returns an error with HTTP status.

```js
function checkIfPdfExists(url) {
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', url);
    xhr.responseType = 'blob';
    xhr.onload = () => {
    if (xhr.status === 200) {
        const blob = xhr.response;
        // check if the blob contains a valid PDF file
        if (blob.type === 'application/pdf') {
        // the Blob object contains a PDF file
        console.log('PDF file retrieved successfully.');
        // you can do something with the PDF file here
        } else {
        console.error('The retrieved file is not a PDF file.');
        // handle the error case here
        }
    } else {
        console.error(`Request failed with status ${xhr.status}.`);
        // handle the error case here
    }
    };
    xhr.send();
}

checkIfPdfExists('https://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf'); // PDF file retrieved successfully.
```

Remember to set the CORS headers correctly, otherwise the code will not work due to browser security.

Comment: CORS is no problem at all. It's just a safeguard. If you are publishing your website on a domain, be sure to properly configure CORS headers on your web server.

Comment: The code first checks whether the status code is equal to 200 - that is, whether the web server accepts the query and sends back a ready response. You can handle more query codes if you want. If the web server simply doesn't exist, it will return an error.

Answer (score 1):

There is only one really functional means to show an object such as PDF is valid and currently accessible, and there is no need for any scripting as it's a pure real-time go/no go situation.

[image]

```
<html><head></head><body>
Here are 3 PDF objects<br><br>
<object data="https://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf">That reference is inaccessible or you dont have a plug-in right now</object><br>
<object data="file:///C:/local/MyPrivateGasBill.pdf">That reference is inaccessible or you dont have a plug-in right now</object><br>
<object data="https://www.example.com/any.pdf">That reference is inaccessible or you dont have a plug-in right now</object><br>
<hr> clearly some will show and others will not
</body></html>
```

Answer (score -1):

What you want to do is check if the remote resource exists. This is a common use case for the `HEAD` HTTP verb. Unlike `GET`, `HEAD` does not return the response body (i.e. does not download the actual PDF) and as a result, is a lot faster and less costly. The good thing is that `HEAD` would still return a 404 status code if the resource does not exist.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods

Since you're using ReactJS, here's a sample `fetch` call that you can make to verify the existence of a remote resource:

```
const pdfExists = async (url) => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(url, { method: 'HEAD' });
    return response.status === 200;
  } catch (err) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

WARNING: The above code is not tested and may need modifications.